# Visual Studio ‘Go To Definition’ menu option behaviour - Why is it inconsistent between C# and VB projects

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2005

When developing in a VS2005+ with C# project and I right click on a framework method/property/type and select ‘Go To Definition’, by default we get a new locked tab with code that has been generated from the framework, labelled appropriately [from metadata].

However when we do the same in a VB.NET project, you get taken to a new tab with the relevant Object Browser view.

This has always struck me as peculiar and was hoping there was a good reason behind it. IMO the object browser is nicer.

**Is there a logical reason for the difference in default visual studio behaviour? If so, what is it?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a choice each team made based on what they believe their respective customers wanted to see.  VB users have a historical attachment to the object browser and many VB features are integrated into it (Go To Def being one of them).  C# made a switch in VS2005 to generate metadata on the fly for their version of GoTo def because they believed their customers would like the behavior better.

Comment: Any way to change this behavior so that VB.NET points directly to my C# file?

Comment: I am a VB.NET user who uses C# a lot, I really can't get used to the metadata classes and find them very annoying. Is there any way I can get rid of it and navigating to the OB when selecting Go 2 def?

Answer (score 0):

You can install Resharper for this.

It'll allow you to choose the default behavior when clicking the "go to definition".