# VS2010 C#: How to view internal classes definitions when I press F12?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

How to view internal classes definitions on Object Browser when I press F12?

In Visual Studion 2010 (C#), if I right-click the word "string" and click "Go to definition" (or press F12), I will be taken to "string [from meta]" source code window. What I want is to display the Object Browser with the said class highlighted just like it does on VB projects.

Can this be done? If no, are there any add-ons that can mimic the desired behaviour?

Comment: Since manojlds gave the link to the previous (and more active) question I would like to have this question deleted to maintain the overall quality of this site. thanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Resharper ( since you asked about add-ons ) or create a macro as suggested here:
[Visual Studio - I want "Go To Definition" to open Object Browser, not "metadata"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3278069/visual-studio-i-want-go-to-definition-to-open-object-browser-not-metadata)

Comment: Thanx for your answer. I voted it up for link to the previous question. But I will not mark it as an answer, if you dont mind. I've tried Resharper (and similar add-ons) before but its benefits does not outweigh the bloat it brings to the IDE. The macro does not work as expected

Comment: @Arvin - ok, but I feel Resharper far far outweighs the bloat it brings ( I have noticed how much more time VS takes to start up after installing Resharper ) I cannot imagine working without REsharper, much like how most people cannot imagine working without VS. Anyway that's my opinion!